# Javascript / jQuery sticky without using css position: fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-position, sticky

I'm looking for a Javascript/jQuery plugin for sticky header that will not switch the element's style to position fixed. Usually, I'm working with this one http://stickyjs.com/ and it works fine.

I'm working on a website with jQuery animation and one of my div has a sticky header with width:100%. But when I move it to the left (for example), the width:100% is now based on the window's width and not his container.

So, is there an existing plugin that does the same thing as the others but keep the position: relative and calculate the scrollTop to apply as the margin-top for my sticky header?

Comment: why do you not want to use `position: fixed`? Also, if you know the solution, you could try to code the solution yourself.

Comment: Because my header has width:100% inside another div smaller that the window's width. When the div switch to position: fixed, it gets bigger (the width starts at the same point but goes until the window's edge)

Comment: Then change the 100% to 95% or something And please post some code and/or a fiddle.

Comment: As an aside, try not to rely on jQuery plugins; it's easy to become dependent on them instead of writing the code yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT 2021**

My answer below is pretty old. I would not recommend to use any JS code for that anymore but simply use CSS with `position: sticky;` which is much easier to implement, but also much more performant/smooth (note: Internet Explorer doesn't support `position: sticky;`).

**Original answer**

So, I solved my problem! Here's my javascript code:

You have to set top:0px as default

```
function relative_sticky(id, topSpacing){

if(!topSpacing){ var topSpacing = 0; }

var el_top = parseFloat(document.getElementById(id).getBoundingClientRect().top);
    el_top = el_top - parseFloat(document.getElementById(id).style.top);
    el_top = el_top * (-1);
    el_top = el_top + topSpacing;

    if(el_top > 0){
    document.getElementById(id).style.top = el_top + "px";
    } else{
    document.getElementById(id).style.top = "0px";
    }
}

window.onscroll = function(){

    relative_sticky("your_element_id", 10);
}
```

It's not very smooth in IE, so I add a delay:

```
var delay = (function(){
  var timer = 0;
  return function(callback, ms){
    clearTimeout (timer);
    timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
  };
})();

window.onscroll = function(){
    
    if(BrowserDetect.browser == "Explorer" || BrowserDetect.browser == "Mozilla"){
    // or your own way to detect browser
    
        delay(function(){
        relative_sticky("admin_users_head", 31);
        }, 200);
    }
    else{
    relative_sticky("admin_users_head", 31);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is old but you should consider using requestAnimationFrame to get smoother animation

Comment: Another approach could have been adding `transform: translateX(0)` to my container which would have made my fixed-position child calculating its width relative to the container instead of the viewport.