# How to position pernament div in custom place on page

Tags: php, html, css

I have problem with positiong div with content in custom place on page pernament way , that means div will be 20px of bottom no matter what:). Problem is that i using online invoice manager for my company and i want littel customization for my invoice . Namely i want signature on invoice will be pernament 20px from bottom, beacuse now signature is moving down whem o add content . In this manager postition: relative is turn off and i can'f figure out how to do it .

I Include html code for invoice , div with signature is class="podpis" and there are inside to div's with txt.

```
<style>
    /*body {
        margin-bottom:177px;
        margin-top:118px;
    }
    */
  page {
    padding: 20 15 20 15;
    font-size: 8;
    font-family: LiberationSans;
  }

  td, th {
    padding: 0.5 1 0 1;
  }

  translation {
    <? if ($invoice['Invoice']['translation_language_id']):?> 
      font-size: 6;
      font-style: italic;
      display: inline;
    <? else: // w przypadku faktury w języku polskim tłumaczenia są ukryte ?>
      display: none;
    <? endif ?>
  }
</style>

<? foreach ($parameters['pages'] as $page): ?>
<page>
  <header id="top" height="85">
    <style>
      .invoice-header {
        position: absolute;
        y: -10;
        text-align: center;
      }
      #top {
      margin-top:118px;
      }
      /* logo */
      .invoice-logo {
        width: 45%;
        height: 40;
        float: left;
      }

      /* main info - start */
      .invoice-main-info {
        width: 48%;
        float: right;
      }

      .invoice-main-info tr th {
        padding: 1.5 0 1.5 0;
      }
      .invoice-main-info tr td {
        padding: 1 0 1 1;
      }

      .invoice-main-info tr:child(0) {
        font-size: 9;
        text-align: center;
        background-gradient-type: linear;
        background-gradient-color1: white;
        background-gradient-color2: lightgrey;
      }

      .invoice-main-info tr td div:child(0) {
        width: 49%;
        float: left;
      }

      .invoice-main-info tr td div:child(1) {
        width: 49%;
        float: right;
      }

      .invoice-main-info tr td div div:child(0) {
        width: 57%;
        float: left;
      }

      .invoice-main-info tr td div div:child(1) {
        width: 42%;
        float: right;
      }
      /* main info - stop */


      /* transaction sides - start */
      .invoice-transaction-side:child(0) {
        width: 48%;
        float: left;
      }

      .invoice-transaction-side:child(1) {
        width: 48%; 
        float: right;
      }
      /* transaction sides - stop */


      .invoice-bar {
        position: absolute;
        y: 71;
        font-size: 10;
        text-align: right;
        padding: 0 1 -0.5 0;
        margin-top: 2;
        border-bottom: 1px;
        background-gradient-type: linear;
        background-gradient-color1: white;
        background-gradient-color2: lightgrey;
        background-gradient-coordinates: 0 0 1 0;
      }
    </style>

    <? if ($invoice['Invoice']['header']): ?>
    <p class="invoice-header"><?=$xml->sanitize($invoice['Invoice']['header']);?></p>
    <? endif ?>

    <div class="invoice-logo">
      <? if ($parameters['logo_path']): ?>
      <img width="80" src="<?=$parameters['logo_path']?>"/>
      <? endif ?>
    </div>

    <div class="invoice-main-info">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Faktura<?=$xml->sanitize($parameters['document_name_suffix'])?> nr <?=$xml->sanitize($invoice['Invoice']['fullnumber'])?></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div>
              <div>Data wystawienia:<br/><translation><?=$translation->get('Invoice:Data wystawienia')?></translation></div>
              <div><?=$xml->sanitize($invoice['Invoice']['date'])?></div>
              <div clear="both"/>
            </div>

            <div>
              <? if(!$invoice['Invoice']['disposaldate_empty']): ?>
                <div>Data sprzedaży:<br/><translation><?=$translation->get('Invoice:Data sprzedaży')?></translation></div>
                <div><?=$xml->sanitize($invoice['Invoice']['disposaldate_format'] == 'month' ? date('Y-m', strtotime($invoice['Invoice']['disposaldate'])) : $invoice['Invoice']['disposaldate'])?></div>
              <? endif ?>
              <div clear="both"/>
            </div>

            <div clear="both"/>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div>
              <div>Termin płatności:<br/><translation><?=$translation->get('Invoice:Termin płatności')?></translation></div>
              <div><?=$xml->sanitize($invoice['Invoice']['paymentdate'])?></div>
              <div clear="both"/>
            </div>

            <div>
              <div>Metoda płatności:<br/><translation><?=$translation->get('Invoice:Metoda płatności')?></translation></div>
              <div><?=$xml->sanitize($invoice['Invoice']['paymentmethod'])?><br/><translation><?=$xml->sanitize($translation->get('Invoice:'.$invoice['Invoice']['paymentmethod']))?></translation></div>
              <div clear="both"/>
            </div>

            <div clear="both"/>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

    <div clear="both"/>

    <? if ($parameters['duplicate']): ?>
    <div position="absolute" x="50" y="25">
      <img width="40" src="/images/duplicate/<?=date("Y-m-d")?>.png"/>
    </div>
    <? endif ?>

    <div class="invoice-transaction-side">
      <h3>Sprzedawca: <translation>(<?=$translation->get('Invoice:Sprzedawca')?>)</translation></h3>
      <p><?=nl2br($xml->sanitize($invoice['Invoice']['sellerinfo']))?></p>
    </div>

    <div class="invoice-transaction-side">
      <h3>Nabywca: <translation>(<?=$translation->get('Invoice:Nabywca')?>)</translation></h3>
      <p><?=nl2br($xml->sanitize($invoice['Invoice']['buyerinfo']))?></p>
    </div>

    <div clear="both"/>

    <div class="invoice-bar">
      <? if ($parameters['show_page_type']): ?>
        <?=$page == 'original' ? 'O R Y G I N A Ł' : 'K O P I A'?>
      <? else: ?>
        <br/>
      <? endif ?>
    </div>
  </header>

  <body>
    <table>
      <header>
        <tr>
          <td width="3%">Lp<br/><translation><?=$translation->get('Invoice:Lp')?></translation></td>
          <td>Nazwa<br/><translation><?=$translation->get('Invoice:Nazwa')?></translation></td>
          <? if ($parameters['show_classification']): ?>
          <td width="7%">PKWiU<br/><translation><?=$translation->get('Invoice:PKWiU')?></translation></td>
          <? endif ?>
          <td width="6%">Jedn.<br/><translation><?=$translation->get('Invoice:Jedn.')?></translation></td>
          <td width="6%">Ilość<br/><translation><?=$translation->get('Invoice:Ilość')?></translation></td>
          <td width="11%"><?=$invoice['Invoice']['tax_evaluation_method'] == 'netto' ? 'Cena netto' : 'Cena brutto'?><br/><translation><?=$translation->get('Invoice:Cena')?></translation></td>
          <? if ($parameters['show_discount']): ?>
          <td column-span="2">Rabat</td>
          <? endif ?>
          <td width="8%">Stawka<br/><translation><?=$translation->get('Invoice:Stawka')?></translation></td>
          <td width="12%">Wartość netto<br/><translation><?=$translation->get('Invoice:Wartość netto')?></translation></td>
          <td width="12%">Wartość brutto<br/><translation><?=$translation->get('Invoice:Wartość brutto')?></translation></td>
        </tr>
      </header>

      <? foreach ($invoiceContents as $key => $invoiceContent): ?>
      <tr class="invoice-content">
        <td><?=$key + 1?></td>
        <td><?=$xml->sanitize($invoiceContent['InvoiceContent']['name'])?></td>
        <? if ($parameters['show_classification']): ?>
        <td><?=$xml->sanitize($invoiceContent['InvoiceContent']['classification'])?></td>
        <? endif ?>
        <td><?=$xml->sanitize($invoiceContent['InvoiceContent']['unit'])?></td>
        <td class="invoice-content-count"><?=$xml->niceFloat($invoiceContent['InvoiceContent']['count'])?></td>
        <td class="invoice-content-price"><?=$xml->currency($invoiceContent['InvoiceContent']['price'])?></td>
        <? if ($parameters['show_discount']): ?>
        <td width="5%"><?=$xml->niceFloat($invoiceContent['InvoiceContent']['discount_percent'])?>%</td>
        <td width="9%"><?=$xml->currency($invoiceContent['InvoiceContent']['discount_amount'])?></td>
        <? endif ?>
        <td><?=$invoiceContent['InvoiceContent']['vatcode']?></td>
        <td class="invoice-content-netto"><?=$xml->currency($invoiceContent['InvoiceContent']['netto'])?></td>
        <td class="invoice-content-brutto"><?=$xml->currency($invoiceContent['InvoiceContent']['brutto'])?></td>
      </tr>
      <? endforeach ?>
    </table>
  </body>

  <footer height="80" margin-top="5">
    <style>
      /* vat sums - start */
      .invoice-sums {
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
      }
      .invoice-sums th {
        font-style: normal;
      }
      /* vat sums - stop */


      /* payment info - start */
      .invoice-payment-info {
        border:0;
        float: right;
        width: <?=$invoice['Invoice']['translation_language_id'] ? '40%' : '30%'?>;
      }
      .invoice-payment-info tr td:child(1) {
        text-align: right;
      }
      /* payment info - stop */


      /* annotations - start */
      .invoice-annotations {
        float: left;
        width: 48%;
      }
      .invoice-annotations p {
        margin-top:3;
      }
      /* annotations - stop */

      .invoice-qr-code {
        width: 25;
        float: right;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 6;
      }

      .invoice-additional-image {
        float: right;
        width: 70;
      }


      /* signatures - start */
      .invoice-signature {
        text-align: center;
        width: 45;
      }
      .invoice-signature:child(0) {
        float: left;
      }
      .invoice-signature:child(1) {
        float: right;
      }
      .invoice-signature span:child(0) {
        font-style: bold;
      }
      .invoice-signature span:child(1) {
        font-size: 7;
      }
      /* signatues - stop */

      .invoice-footer {
        margin-top: 5;
        text-align: center;
      }
    </style>

    <table class="invoice-sums">
      <tr>
        <th width="25%">Stawka VAT<br/><translation><?=$translation->get('Invoice:Stawka VAT')?></translation></th>
        <th width="25%">Wartość Netto<br/><translation><?=$translation->get('Invoice:Wartość netto')?></translation></th>
        <th width="25%">Kwota VAT<br/><translation><?=$translation->get('Invoice:Kwota VAT')?></translation></th>
        <th width="25%">Wartość Brutto<br/><translation><?=$translation->get('Invoice:Wartość brutto')?></translation></th>
      </tr>

      <? foreach ($invoice['VatContent'] as $vatContent): ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?=$vatContent['VatCode']['label']?></td>
          <td><?=$xml->currency($vatContent['netto'])?></td>
          <td><?=$xml->currency($vatContent['tax'])?></td>
          <td><?=$xml->currency($vatContent['brutto'])?></td>
        </tr>
      <? endforeach ?>

      <tr>
        <td>Razem <translation>(<?=$translation->get('Invoice:Razem')?>)</translation></td>
        <td><?=$xml->currency($invoice['Invoice']['vat_content_netto'])?></td>
        <td><?=$xml->currency($invoice['Invoice']['vat_content_tax'])?></td>
        <td><?=$xml->currency($invoice['Invoice']['vat_content_brutto'])?></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <table class="invoice-payment-info">
      <tr>
        <td>Razem: <translation>(<?=$translation->get('Invoice:Razem')?>)</translation></td>
        <td><?=$xml->currency($invoice['Invoice']['total'])?> <?=$invoice['Invoice']['currency']?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="60%">Zapłacono: <translation>(<?=$translation->get('Invoice:Zapłacono')?>)</translation></td>
        <td width="40%"><?=$xml->currency($invoice['Invoice']['alreadypaid_initial'])?> <?=$invoice['Invoice']['currency']?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Pozostało: <translation>(<?=$translation->get('Invoice:Do zapłaty')?>)</translation></td>
        <td><?=$xml->currency($invoice['Invoice']['total'] - $invoice['Invoice']['alreadypaid_initial'])?> <?=$invoice['Invoice']['currency']?></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <div clear="both"/>

    <div class="invoice-annotations">
      <? if ($invoice['Invoice']['legal_annotations']): ?>
      <p><?=$xml->sanitize($invoice['Invoice']['legal_annotations'])?></p>
      <? endif ?>

      <? if ($invoice['Invoice']['associated_document_annotations']): ?>
      <?=$xml->sanitize($invoice['Invoice']['associated_document_annotations'])?>
      <? endif ?>

      <? if ($invoice['Invoice']['description']): ?>
      <p>
        Uwagi: <translation>( <?=$translation->get('Invoice:Uwagi')?>)</translation><br/>
        <?=nl2br($invoice['Invoice']['description'])?>
      </p>
      <? endif ?>

      <? if ($invoice['Invoice']['currency'] != 'PLN' && !$parameters['show_invoice_foreign_currency_vat_content']): ?>
      <p>
        1 <?=$invoice['Invoice']['currency']?> = <?=number_format($invoice['Invoice']['currency_exchange'], 4, ',', ' ')?> PLN<br/>
        Kurs z dnia: <?=$invoice['Invoice']['currency_date']?><br/>
        Numer tabeli: <?=$invoice['Invoice']['currency_label']?>
      </p>
      <? endif ?>
    </div>

    <? if ($parameters['invoice_send_external_type'] != 'none'): ?>
    <div class="invoice-qr-code">
      <a href="http://<?=$parameters['app_server']?>/faktura/<?=$invoice['Invoice']['id']?>/<?=$invoice['Invoice']['hash']?>">
        <qr-code>http://<?=$parameters['app_server']?>/faktura/<?=$invoice['Invoice']['id']?>/<?=$invoice['Invoice']['hash']?></qr-code><br/>
        panel klienta
      </a>
    </div>
    <? endif ?>
    <div clear="right"/>

    <? if ($parameters['additional_image_path']): ?>
    <div class="invoice-additional-image">
      <img width="70" src="<?=$parameters['additional_image_path']?>"/>
    </div>
    <? endif ?>

    <div clear="both" margin-bottom="5"/>

    <? if ($parameters['signature_image_path']): ?>
      <img width="70" src="<?=$parameters['signature_image_path']?>"/>
    <? endif ?>


    <div class="podpis" margin-top="2">
      <div class="invoice-signature">
        <span><?=$xml->sanitize($invoice['Invoice']['user_name'])?></span><br/>
        <span>Imię i nazwisko osoby uprawnionej do wystawiania faktury</span>
      </div>

      <div class="invoice-signature">
        <span><br/></span><br/>
        <span>Imię i nazwisko osoby uprawnionej do odbioru faktury</span>
      </div>

      <div clear="both"/>
    </div>

    <? if ($invoice['Invoice']['footer']): ?>
    <p class="invoice-footer"><?=$xml->sanitize($invoice['Invoice']['footer']);?></p>
    <? endif ?>
  </footer>
</page>

<? if ($page == 'original' && $parameters['address']): // opcja adresu korespondecyjnego na odwrocie oryginału ?>
<page padding-left="119" padding-top="255">
  <?=nl2br($xml->sanitize($invoice['Invoice']['buyeraddress']));?>
</page>
<? endif ?>
<? endforeach ?>

<? if ($parameters['leaflet']): // druczek przelewu ?>
<page padding="20 0 0 20">
  <? for ($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++): ?>
  <div width="164" height="106" background-image="/images/reports/invoices/leaflet_<?=$i?>.png">
    <style>
      entry {
        margin-left: 22.5;
        margin-top: 4.6;
      }
    </style>

    <entry><?=$xml->sanitize($invoice['CompanyDetail']['name'])?></entry>
    <entry>
      <?=$xml->sanitize($invoice['CompanyDetail']['street'])?> <?=$xml->sanitize($invoice['CompanyDetail']['building_number'])?><?=$invoice['CompanyDetail']['flat_number'] ? "/".$xml->sanitize($invoice['CompanyDetail']['flat_number']) : ""?>,
      <?=$xml->sanitize($invoice['CompanyDetail']['zip'])?> <?=$xml->sanitize($invoice['CompanyDetail']['city'])?>
    </entry>
    <entry letter-spacing="5"><?=str_replace(" ", "", $xml->sanitize($invoice['CompanyDetail']['bank_account']))?></entry>
    <entry margin-left="98"><?=str_replace(".", ",", $invoice['Invoice']['remaining'])?></entry>
    <entry><br/></entry>
    <entry><?=$xml->sanitize($invoice['ContractorDetail']['name'])?></entry>
    <entry>
      <?=$xml->sanitize($invoice['ContractorDetail']['street'])?>,
      <?=$xml->sanitize($invoice['ContractorDetail']['zip'])?> <?=$xml->sanitize($invoice['ContractorDetail']['city'])?>
    </entry>
    <entry><?=$xml->sanitize($invoice['Invoice']['fullnumber'])?></entry>
  </div>
  <? endfor ?>
</page>
<? endif ?>
```

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for the position:fixed CSS attribute.

See [this fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/eLho4yz4/)

```
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top:20px;
  left:20px;
}
```

Comment: Only static(defualt) and absolute position is allowed by this manager . 
I wonder if is diffrent way to do this , or maybe change the div sequence in code but i dont know PHP that good, to do this.

Comment: Bahahahah. That's awful. This is literally what you need.

Comment: I have an idea: Just do it, and don't tell the manager how you accomplished it.

Comment: I know that , but is locked . I cant even put left , top only Y and X :)

Comment: It not my manager is online manager aplication to invoice and finance stuff.

Comment: Can you add javascript? You can fix the position absolutely and calculate the top/left with javascript.

Comment: Yes i think i can add javascript , but i really don know this code language.

Comment: See this stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21006140/javascript-jquery-sticky-without-using-css-position-fixed

Comment: Can i have request i dont know if i do good this my div id is podpis. Can you help me with that

Comment: Good luck! If you can't use CSS position fixed, javascript is going to be your next best bet. If that still doesnt work, you can try doing something like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/7asb188u/

Comment: Jsfiddel is not that . I want just position div pernament i custom place on page.

Comment: function relative_sticky(#podpis, topSpacing){

if(!topSpacing){ var topSpacing = 0; }

var el_top = parseFloat(document.getElementById(#podpis).getBoundingClientRect().top);
    el_top = el_top - parseFloat(document.getElementById(#podpis).style.top);
    el_top = el_top * (-1);
    el_top = el_top + topSpacing;

    if(el_top > 0){
    document.getElementById(#podpis).style.top = el_top + "px";
    } else{
    document.getElementById(#podpis).style.top = "0px";
    }
}
'code'
window.onscroll = function(){

    relative_sticky("#podpis", 10);
}

Comment: Sorry i cant edit this to be more clear :/ . is this correct?

Comment: This might help (view page source): http://hamiltonlucas.com/podpis.html

Comment: When i give position absolute to div warper that change position , but when i add more content(text) above this div  , this div is lowering. And i want lock this div no matter how long or big content is on one height on page

Comment: Set style="top: 50px;" or whatever value is appropriate, and then it should start there every time.

Comment: When i add more content div still lowering :/

Comment: Problem is solve . Thank you for your answers and advice .