# How can i change div position by javascript

Tags: javascript

Is possible to change div position like( absolute or relative by css) but use java script

Code for example

```
<div id="podpis" margin-top="2">
      <div class="invoice-signature">
        <span><?=$xml->sanitize($invoice['Invoice']['user_name'])?></span><br/>
        <span>First name and second name osoby uprawnionej do wystawiania faktury</span>
      </div>

      <div class="invoice-signature">
        <span><br/></span><br/>
        <span>First name and second name</span>
      </div>

      <div clear="both"/>
    </div>
```

I want change position of div `id="podpis"`.

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Why the downvotes? This definitely an example question. He clearly stated what he's trying to do ('I want to change position of `div id="podpis"`'), and supplied example code so we know what we're looking at. Not sure what went wrong there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the position value:

```
document.getElementById('podpis').style.position = 'relative';
```

or

```
document.getElementById('podpis').style.position = 'absolute';
```

And based on your comments it sounds to me like you want to have the `podpis` stay at the bottom of the page no matter what?

```
//div stays in same place on screen no matter what, even when scrolling
document.getElementById('podpis').style.position = 'fixed';
//div goes to the bottom of the page
document.getElementById('podpis').style.bottom = '0';
```

Comment: all in need to do right now is tu put tag <script></script> and copy/paste this second option , when i put there 20 it will be 20 px from the bottom ?

Comment: Ok problem i solve . Thank you for your help and advice .

Comment: Great to know it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could using :

```
<script>
   document.getElementById('podpis').style.position = 'absolute';
   document.getElementById('podpis').style.position = 'relative';
</script>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok , can you perhaps give me ready code beacuse i dont really know java. I asking about java solution beacuse on my app css is blocked.

Comment: You have to add the tag in my answer in your html page, inside the head tag or just before `</body>` and that depending of when you want to change position.

Comment: but where i have to put top . left or x , y  . To put dive where i want

Comment: I want to this div be pernament on bottom of page .

Comment: _I want to this div be pernament on bottom of page_ i can't give you an answer without reviewing the full code of your page

Comment: Ok . I want to put div on bottom of page , and he will be there on same height no matter if content(text) above is bigger or longer . Now when i add content div is lowering . I wanna to be on one height which i set to him  and he will stay there no matter how content will be above.

Comment: @kancer *"Ok , can you perhaps give me ready code"* Stack Overflow is supposed to be a way to help you learn to solve your problems. Not be a free code writing service.

Comment: Okey, try to make an example in jsfiddle.com and put it in the OP.

Comment: This is link to my earliner post here and there is my code .

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37886020/how-to-position-pernament-div-in-custom-place-on-page/37886444?noredirect=1#comment63236712_37886444